# Symfony delete record after set time

Tags: mysql, symfony1, doctrine

I am making a sort of session table that adds a new record to a table when a user accesses a particular form.

My question is is there any way of deleting a record after a certain amount of time after it was created? For example if the record was last updated at 10:00, it would be deleted at 11:00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is to create a cron job. Create the cron job that runs a symfony task that deletes records that are greater than 12hrs old. Then set the cron to run every hour.